# Firebase Functions Cloud SQL Too Many connections

Tags: javascript, mysql, firebase, google-cloud-sql

I’m working on an application that uses Firebase Functions as a API interface between my web application and Google Cloud SQL (MySQL 5.7).

I have a process for importing records from the client app; basically the client app reads a CSV file then executes a function for every row in the CSV file. The function executes three or four queries during processing of the record (checking to see if the main record exists, creating it and/or other needed records, updating a stats record for this process).

The function’s called sequentially for each row, so there’s never more than one request (row) processed at a time executing 3 or 4 queries before returning data to the client app which then processes the next row (async/await).

The process works great for CSV files with 1 to 100 rows. As soon as it goes above about 900 rows, the Firebase Functions starts reporting `ERROR Error: ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections`
My code, shown below, originally had a connection limit of 10, but I bumped it up to 100 connections but it still fails.

Here’s my code that executes the SQL queries:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as mysql from 'mysql';

export async function executeQuery(cmd: string) {
    const mySQLConfig = {
        host: functions.config().sql.prodhost,
        user: functions.config().sql.produser,
        password: functions.config().sql.prodpswd,
        database: functions.config().sql.proddatabase,
        connectionLimit: 100,
    }

    var pool: any;
    if (!pool) {
        pool = mysql.createPool(mySQLConfig);
    }

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        //@ts-ignore
        pool.query(cmd, function (error, results) {
            if (error) {
                return reject(error);
            }
            resolve(results);
        });
    });
}
```

As I understand it, with a pool like I think I’ve implemented above, each request will get a connection up to the max connections. Each connection will automatically return to the pool once its done processing the request. So, even if it takes a while to release the connection, with the connection limit at 100, I should be able to process quite a few rows (20 or so at least) before there’s contention for connections and then the process will queue up and wait for free connections before continuing. If that’s right, what’s happening here?

I found an article here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections that describes some additional settings I can use to tweak connection management:

```
// 'connectTimeout' is the maximum number of milliseconds before a timeout
// occurs during the initial connection to the database.
connectTimeout: 10000, 
// 'acquireTimeout' is the maximum number of milliseconds to wait when
// checking out a connection from the pool before a timeout error occurs.
acquireTimeout: 10000, 
// 'waitForConnections' determines the pool's action when no connections are
// free. If true, the request will queued and a connection will be presented
// when ready. If false, the pool will call back with an error.
waitForConnections: true, // Default: true
// 'queueLimit' is the maximum number of requests for connections the pool
// will queue at once before returning an error. If 0, there is no limit.
queueLimit: 0, // Default: 0
```

I’m tempted to try bumping up the timeouts, but I’m not sure whether that’s actually impacting me here.
Since I’m running this in Firebase Functions (Google Cloud Functions under the covers), do these settings even really apply?  Isn’t my function’s VM resetting after every execution or at least my function terminating after every execution? Does the pool even exist in this context? If not, then how do I do this type of processing in Functions?

One option is, of course, to push all of my processing to the function, just send up a JSON object for the row array and let the function process them all at once. This, I think, should make proper use of pools, but I’m worried I’ll bump up against execution limits in Functions (5 minutes) which is why I built it like I did.

Comment: Can someone please help me here? I need help understanding how to implement connection pools in a Firebase/Google Cloud environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid developer trick, I was paying such close attention to my pool code that I missed that I'm declaring the pool variable in the wrong place. Moving the pool declaration outside of the method fixed my problem. With the code the way it was, I was creating a pool with every SQL query which quickly used up all of my connections.